# A basis of polynomials of the same degree for homogeneous polynomials of two variables

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials

Let $\mathcal{P}_l$ be the linear subspace of the complex-valued homogeneous polynomials on $\mathbb{R}^2$ of degree $l$. The polynomials of the form $(ax+by)^l$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ do span the space $\mathcal{P}_l$

In the book I read this (B.C.Hall), he gives an indication as follows : if we denote by $V_l$ the span of the $(ax+by)^l$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$, Remark that since $V_l$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{P_l}\equiv \mathbb{C}^{l+1}$, it is a closed subspace and thus if $\gamma(t)$ is a smooth curve in $V_l$, the derivative $\gamma'(t)$ will also lie in $V_l$.
Does anyone know how to use this indication to show that $\mathcal{P}_l=V_l$ ?
Any help on that will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For any function $\gamma(t):[0,1]\to V_l$ we have $\displaystyle {\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_0)\over t-t_0}$ belongs to $V_l.$ By closedness we get that $\gamma'(t_0)\in V_l.$
The same arguments is valid for higher derivatives of $\gamma(t).$

The space $\mathcal{P}_l$ is spanned by monomials $x^ky^{l-k},$ $0\le k\le l.$ It suffices to show that $x^ky^{l-k}\in V_l.$

Consider the function $$f_t(x,y)=(tx+y)^l=\sum_{j=0}^l{l\choose j}x^jy^{l-j}t^j,\quad 0\le t\le 1$$
For $0\le k\le l$ we have
$${d^k\over dt^k} f_t(x,y)=\sum_{j=k}^l {l\choose j}x^jy^{l-j}j(j-1)\ldots (j-k+1)\,t^{j-k} $$
Plugging in $t=0$ gives
$${d^k\over dt^k} f_t(x,y)\Big |_{t=0}={l\choose k}k!\, x^ky^{l-k}$$
By the first part of the answer $x^ky^{k-l}\in V_l.$